# Can I have two maps in one options_for_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to know if there is any way to have two "mappings" in just one `options_for_select` inside my `select_tag`.

```
select_tag('client_id', auction_order.client ? auction_order.client.rut_to_human : options_for_select(Client.all.map{ |c| [c.rut_to_human, c.id, c.full_name]}), placeholder: "Adjudicatario", class: "auction_order_input auction_order_client form-control shadow_big", data: {ao_id: auction_order.id, current_client: auction_order.client})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not use salutations ("Hi!"), valedictions ("Thanks") or signatures. Also, emoticons aren't necessary and get stripped. Stack Overflow is not a discussion board, it's an online programming-problem resource book. Friendliness is OK, but be concise/accurate and brief. Correct grammar is very important too. I'd recommend reading your way through the "[tour]", "[help]" and "[ask]" pages  for the site, paying close attention to how to ask questions.